# setup project .net 4 prerequisite

Tags: c#, installation

I added .NET Framework 4 to my setup package as a prerequisite. When installing this package, an error reports that installing .NET 4 requires WIC "windows imaging component", which I've also added as a prerequisite.

But the installation failed due to a newer version of this component being already installed.

I want to ask how to check whether this WIC is installed or not and skip installing it when there is a newer version?

Comment: From my knowledge .NET Framework 4 doesn't have dependencies. On which Windows version do you encounter the error?

Comment: it might be asking for Windows installer which is a dependency for installing .NET build applications. Try installing windows installer 3.1 or above and see if things sort out

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. .NET does depend on this component. You could consider creating your own bootstrapper package using this: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg

Answer (score 0):

At your package add check condition for the prerequisites so that if it is already installed then don't install.